# Calculate two different sums from a single column, based on different conditions in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table called `daily_purchases` with

```
item    purchases    purchase_date
paper     1            2020-01-15
paper     3            2020-02-10
pencil    2            2020-01-17
pencil    3            2020-02-05
```

I want to get 7 day and 30 day sums like so:

```
item    sevenday    thirtyday
paper   1           4
pencil  2           5
```

I can get them separately, but cannot get the above. I have tried what's below, but instead of separating the totals by `item` as expected, I get the same total for all items, like so:

```
item    sevenday    thirtyday
paper   2           5
pencil  2           5
```

Here is what I tried:

```
SELECT item,
    (SELECT sum(purchases) FROM `daily_purchases` WHERE datediff(CURDATE(), purchase_date) < 8) as 'sevenday',
    (SELECT sum(purchases) FROM `daily_purchases` WHERE datediff(CURDATE(), purchase_date) < 31) as 'thirtyday'
FROM daily_purchases  
GROUP BY item
ORDER BY 'thirtyday' DESC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT item,
  SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), purchase_date) < 8 THEN purchases ELSE 0 END) 'sevenday',
  SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), purchase_date) < 31 THEN purchases ELSE 0 END) 'thirtyday'
FROM daily_purchases  
GROUP BY item
```

Comment: man, I tried that but obviously I had some aspect wrong. Thanks!

Comment: BTW, how come the alias (sevenday) works without AS?

Comment: The AS keyword is optional in most databases.

Answer (score 0):

In thirtyday and sevenday, you don't have any filters for "item".

But why not use JOIN? 
Example:

```
SELECT item, sevenday.sum as 7d, thirtyday.sum as 30d
FROM daily_purchases 
LEFT JOIN 
    ((SELECT sum(purchases) as sum FROM daily_purchases
      WHERE datediff(CURDATE(), purchase_date) < 8) as 'sevenday')
   ON daily_purchases.item = sevenday.item
LEFT JOIN 
    ((SELECT sum(purchases) as sum FROM `daily_purchases` 
      WHERE datediff(CURDATE(), purchase_date) < 31) as 'thirtyday') 
   ON daily_purchases.item = thirtyday.item

GROUP BY item
ORDER BY 'thirtyday' DESC
```

I also suggest to write <=7 instead of < 8, it's better for readability.